# Having Problem with Command Phase Script Execution on a project I received

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I received a project from a client for an improvement and modifications. The Project contains with lots of podfiles. I did install pods and updated correctly. But When I run I am getting following Run Time Error:

```
/Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HeraApp-gjcgxguhtaccgtgslqunvgsaljlj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/****App.build/Debug-iphoneos/****App.build/Script-E72B2D3B2705AC7C00F5AF8B.sh: line 2: /Users/xxx/Downloads/The: No such file or directory
```

I searched google and tried out many solutions like... deleting Runscript, Keychain lock and unlock, clean derived data, Delete PodFile and PodLock, clean and run. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Go to the app Build Settings and look at line 2 in Script-E72B2D3B2705AC7C00F5AF8B.sh. Script is trying to find "/Users/xxx/Downloads/The" path but It couldn't find.

Comment: @AhmetSina Is there anyway to run without that script incase

Comment: It depends on your project. If you delete this script, maybe it works, maybe not. But I recommend finding the relevant folder and adding its path. Or you can delete this line if it is irrelevant.